# Why do Japanese characters behave differently on CSS width animations?

Tags: css, utf-8, css-transitions

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agVbPE?editors=1100

Best visualized. When transitioning the width of an element, Japanese characters appear and disappear in a choppy, non-smooth way while english and other seemingly random utf-8 characters do not.

```css
.border {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.border:hover {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
トムヤムクンスープ
</div>

<div class="border">
ENGLISH 
</div>

<div class="border">
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
</div>

<div class="border">
ぁぁぁぁぁぁぁぁぁ 
</div>

<div class="border">
ൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾൾ
</div>
```

Getting rid of `text-overflow: ellipsis;` has solved this problem for me locally.

Comment: Edited to include code.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for point that out. Also to note if you have `white-space: nowrap;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` the choppy animation still occurs.

Comment: Isn’t everything choppy once you add `text-overflow: ellipsis`? You’re specifically requesting for anything that would be cut off to be replaced with an ellipsis, so characters will always appear and disappear in their entireties. (Although the ellipsis doesn’t actually show up for me in the case of Japanese text.)

Comment: Without text-overflow: ellipsis and without white-space: nowrap Japanese characters or specifically hiragana or katakana will be choppy while many other characters are not. But yeah you're right about everything being choppy with text-overflow: ellipsis.